# Read integers from file and ignore whitespace in C

Tags: c, whitespace, scanf

I'm learning C, and part of a program I'm writing in C is to check whether my txt file contains less than or more than 81 values, and if all of the values are integers. I use fscanf to read value from file, but it also reads whitespace. How can I ignore whitespaces and make it read only integers or characters?

My code returns 162, which contains 81 integers and whitespaces.

This is the txt file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2
4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4
6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5
7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8


#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
FILE * input_values;

input_values = fopen("text.txt","r");

    if (input_values == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! Could not open file.\n");
    }

int ch, counter = 0;

ch = fscanf(input_values, "%d");
    while (ch != EOF) {
            counter++;
            ch = fscanf(input_values, "%d");
    }

    printf("num %i",counter);
    fclose(input_values);

}
```

Comment: You're not passing an output variable to fscanf for your integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in an output variable for `fscanf`, I'm surprised your code isn't crashing:

```
int num;
fscanf(input_values, "%d", &num);
```

It works as expected if you change both your `fscanf`'s

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. How can I check if there is any non-integer in the txt file?

Comment: Check return value of `fscanf`, it will return `0` if it encounters a non integer.